# textColor override textColorPrimary and textColorPrimaryDark

Tags: android, styles, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

> I have applied a theme to my app but when I use textColor properties it override all other properties like textColorPrimary.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#186925</item>

    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF0000</item> <!-- for check box when checked -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#bbc40c</item> <!-- for check box when normal -->
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#325289</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textColor">#084fe9</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>

    <!--<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/slide_right</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/slide_left</item>-->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
<style name="HeaderText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>
<style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

**my Layout file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionNumberTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Score : 20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconIv"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/scoreTv"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/questionNumberTv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[11]" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iconIv" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fiftyfiftyBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup2" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questionTitle">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/votesTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_expand_less_green_24dp"
        android:text="20"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fiftyfiftyBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentCountTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_expand_less_green_24dp"
        android:text="35"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/votesTv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fiftyfiftyBtn" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

when I Uncomment `android:textColor` , `android:textColorPrimary` color is override by `android:textColor`. I want my title/large text to use **textColorPrimary** and for medium and small I wanna use **textColorPrimaryDark** as said in their documentation.

> before that the button text color is set by the textColorPrimary.

How could I use two text Color scheme for whole my app. using textColorPrimary and textColorPrimaryDark.

Or I have to create two `textStyle` and set them to each `View`. Is there a better approach to achieve what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define two styles and set your desired attributes there. It is cleaner to read and understandable. And also good behaviour to set your own style in textview.

Here is a sample you should do:

```
<style name="textStyle1" parent="android:TextAppearance">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
            <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
        </style>

        <style name="textStyle2" parent="android:TextAppearance">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
            <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        </style>
```

Then use this style on your expected textview like this:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            style="@style/textStyleMedium"
           ........ />
```

Remove the below tags on your app theme:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#186925</item>
        <!-- <item name="android:textColor">#084fe9</item> -->
```

Purpose of different color:

**TextColor** is just the xml attribute to set a color to the text of any given view.

**TextColorPrimary** is the default text color for enabled buttons and Large Textviews.

**TextColorSecondary** is the default text color for Medium and Small Textviews.

**colorPrimaryDark** is the color of the status bar.

> In order to achieve this you should remove `textColor` that override other colors.

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
```

inside your textView  in xml . Then it will apply it to all your View. In this manner you don't have to set style to all ..

Comment: So what is the purpose of textColorPrimary and textColorPrimaryDark is??

Comment: that is something I mention in my question. So my title is a larger one . How do I set it to large . I mean how my question title changes on basis of textColorPrimary or textColorPrimaryDark ??

Comment: Would you please try it to define the textAppearance specifically : android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" or 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
 Thanks. Don't know it will work or not but hope it will solve the problem

Comment: I said at what stage( at what sp/dp) OS decide it is a textApperanceLarge  or textApperanceSmall . I have used different size of textView but none of them adopt the textColor of textColorPrimary or Dark